# Getting segmentaition fault with subset dp problem

Tags: subset, dynamic-programming

Given a set of numbers, check whether it can be partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of elements in both subsets is same or not
I am getting segmentation fault in C++(g++ 5.4) with a this problem.
This is where i submitted my solution in C++

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subset-sum-problem/0

I am checking if the array can be divided into two parts with equal sum. So I am just checking if there exists a subset with sum equal to half the sum of the array

I have implemented the below logic with dynamic programming

Let dp[i][j] denote yes or no whether a subset with sum j is possible to form with elements in the range [0, i](both inclusive) where i is 0-based index. I have done nothing new with this traditional problem. But I am getting segmentation fault. The program is giving correct output for small test cases. What mistake have I made

I haven't used any comments because I have done nothing new. Hope it is understandable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<cstdio>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;


bool isVowel(char c){
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}

bool isLower(char c){
    return 97 <= c && c <= 122;
}


int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);
    cout << setprecision(10);

    ll t, n;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        cin >> n;
        ll a[n];
        ll sum = 0;

        for (ll i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> a[i];
            sum += a[i];
        }

        if (sum % 2) {
            cout << "NO" << '\n';
            continue;
        }

        sum /= 2;
        ll dp[n][sum + 1];
        for (ll i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(ll j = 0; j < sum + 1; j++) {
                dp[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for (ll i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            dp[i][a[i]] = 1;
            dp[i][0] = 1;
        }


        for (ll i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (ll j = 1; j < sum + 1; j++){
                if (j - a[i] > 0) {
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - a[i]];
                }

                dp[i][j] |= dp[i - 1][j];
            }
        }

        cout << (dp[n - 1][sum] ? "YES" : "NO") << '\n';

    }
}
```

Comment: With what input does the segmentation error occur. On a first glance I didn't find any obvious errors, and gcc sanitizers also show no errors.
Also, try to post shorter code. There is lots of stuff in this code, that is not relevant to your problem. Like the isVowel method, the while loop, ...

Comment: Sorry for the extra code. Well I don't know where exactly is it giving error. We can't see the test case. It will only show the test case if some wrong output is produced. But here segmentation fault is the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation fault is due to

```
ll dp[n][sum + 1];
```

Even though the constraints say **1 <= N<= 100, 0 <= arr[i]<= 1000**, the test cases used are probably much larger, so **ll dp[n][sum + 1]** will end up taking some serious stack memory, use

```
bool dp[n][sum + 1];
```

It should work fine.

On a side note, avoid using ll randomly, use them according to the constraints.